# Differential of a smooth covering map is always invertible?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces, tangent-spaces, pushforward

If $f: E \to M$ is a smooth covering map between manifolds, is it true that the differential (or the push-forward) $df_p : T_p E \to T_{f(p)}M$ is invertible for every $p\in E$?

I think this should be true since every smooth covering map is a local diffeomorphism, hence both a smooth immersion and submersion.

Is my reasoning correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you gave the answer!